# Integrate existing Login Infrastructure from Node JS in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, passport.js

I have in my backend server, which was built with Node JS, an authentication with the package "passport-azure-ad". I put the important elements of the code here in the post.
Basically, the process is that when I call the URI "localhost:3000/login", I start the authentication and (if you are not already logged in) the login window I get from Azure pops up. After the login, it routes to the callback URI.

I.e. I have the complete "login infrastructure" I need for my use case. However, now I built a frontend with Angular and unfortunately I have absolutely no idea how to best proceed to integrate the authentication I built in Node JS into my frontend (Angular)?
I want to check if there is a login when calling my frontend (localhost:4200), if not I want to route to 3000/login to trigger the Microsoft login window. I do this check in the backend with the ensureAuthenticated function. Now I wonder how to call all this from the frontend? It would be nice if someone could support me on this, any tips or any suitable sources would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

```
// session management
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// check if logged in
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/login');
};

// call azures login page
app.get('/login',
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect')
);

// callback uri after authentication
app.post('/auth/oauth/callback',
  function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect',
      {
        failureRedirect: '/failure',
      }
    )(req, res, next);
  },
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/account');
});

// protected ressource
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('Login succesfull!');
});

// logout
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    req.session.destroy();
    res.send('Ausgeloggt!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an SPA like Angular, you can't no longer use this kind of authentication flow by using passport strategies to authenticate to third party endpoints like Microsoft/Google.

Instead, you start the OAuth2.0 flow from your Angular application straight to the Microsoft authentication endpoint. Tokens will be used for further authentication.

Some links:

- [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
- [Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from an Angular single-page application (SPA) using auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code)